# Non-breaking en dash, not a hyphen

Tags: html, character-encoding

I know in html there is a non-breaking hyphen (`#8209`), but I am needing a non-breaking en dash (`#8211`). They are used differently. Is there proper way of doing this besides wrapping the text and en-dash with no-break code throughout my document, like:

```
<nobr> TEXT #8211 TEXT </nobr>
```

Comment: You could try using the [word joiner character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_joiner), which would be `&#8288;`, either side of the en dash.

Comment: (Regarding typing `<nobr>` etc. without it turning into HTML: [How do I insert inline code snippets on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293465/1115360))

Comment: You say they are used differently. I am super curious: what the difference between a non-breaking hyphen and a non-breaking dash? Maybe I am using the dash wrong?

Comment: @SherylHohman A hyphen (-) is a punctuation mark that's used to join words or parts of words. It's not interchangeable with other types of dashes. A dash is longer than a hyphen and is commonly used to indicate a range or a pause. The most common types of dashes are the en dash (–) and the em dash (—).

Comment: Cool. What are em & en dashes used for? Do em/en stand for something? I learned something -- I've been using hyphen (a "regular dash") for ranges, when I should be using either an en or em longer dash. I have a website to update accordingly :-)

Comment: Ok found a good, explanation: https://www.scribbr.com/language-rules/dashes/#:~:text=The%20en%20dash%20is%20approximately,a%20break%20in%20a%20sentence. **Hyphen** (shortest width): join words together. **En dash** (width of letter n): indicate a range between items. **Em dash** (width of letter m): indicate an informal break, pause, or change in tone. Similar to comma/parenthesis, or period/semi-colon. Use sparingly. All are used without a space. Alternatively, an en dash, but with spaces, can be used like an em dash (more common in British English), but use only 1 "em style" in any document.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try surrounding the en dash with the Word-Joiner character (#8288).

```
TEXT&#8288;&#8211;&#8288;TEXT
```

Answer (score 4):

This question was driving me crazy in a recent project. I found it hard to believe that en dashes are by default breaking characters. If you're okay inserting extra characters with html, then `&#8288;` works well. Note, only a word-joiner is necessary *after* the en dash, since I believe they don't break before.

For a number of reasons, manually putting extra characters everywhere in my source HTML was not going to work for me, and I came up with a javascript solution which automatically applies a `.nobreak` CSS class to any en dash and the character immediately following it.

```
<style>
    .nobreak {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
</style>

<body>

    <p>This is a paragraph with a number range, 1–34, and it will never break after the en dash.</p>

    <script>
        $("body").html(function(_, html) {
            return  html.replace(/(–.)/g, '<span class="nobreak">$1</span>')
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

An even simpler solution might be to use the same script to automatically insert `&#8288;` after en dashes. Just change the js to:

```
$("body").html(function(_, html) {
    return  html.replace(/–/g, '–&#8288;')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As per of this [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_misc_symbols.asp), and other answer about the word joiner `&#8211;`, the following HTML should produce a non breakable en dash:

> If the character does not have an HTML entity, you can use the decimal
>   (dec) or hexadecimal (hex) reference.

```html
<p>
Will break : 
<br />
 TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT&#8211;TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
<p>

<p>
Won't break (word joiner):     
<br />
TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT&#8288;&#8211;&#8288;TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
<p>
```